# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when using Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm working on `ViewPager` with multiple images using `Picasso`. But it gives me this error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method load(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/squareup/picasso/RequestBuilder; in class Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.picasso.Picasso' appears in /data/app/com.example.myapp-1/base.apk)

when used like

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(url)
        .centerCrop()
        .resize(imageView.getMeasuredWidth(),imageView.getMeasuredHeight())
        .error(R.drawable.detail_placeholder)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.detail_placeholder)
        .into(imageView);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Clean and built` and use the latest `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

Comment: @MD I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Jump in `Android Studio`.

Comment: that's not really an answer

Comment: What context are you using as `mContext`?

Comment: That's the context in my ViewPager adapter class

Comment: use context of parent class rather then using context of adapter. i.e replase `mContext` with `yourParentClass.this`

Answer (score 0):

try with this code i am using it in my app right now

```
// "this" is the context here
Picasso.with(this)
       .load(personPhotoUrl)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
       .error(R.drawable.avatar)
       .into(mImageViewProfilePic);
```

my Picasso jar file version 2.4.0

if that don't you can try to load image with image loader library or Gilde.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding OkHttp dependency into your build.gradle (app-level):

> compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:+'
>
> compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:+'

Edit: Oh, sorry, you're using Eclipse, so you may have to get the jar file instead:

> https://search.maven.org/remote_content?g=com.squareup.okhttp3&a=okhttp&v=LATEST